# WinUI x:Bind to Model property not updating UI

Tags: c#, winui-3

This is the first time I have used WinUI.  I have all of the information I need pulling in, but the binding back to the UI to display the data after async functions isn't updating the UI controls.

I have a view model that is handling the streams to load in the string from the user's selected file, and storing that `List<string>` in the model object.  The model object implements  `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  I must not understanding completely the relationship between `x:bind` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`  because nothing is set from the view to the `PropertyChanged` event.

```
public class PCCBill : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string importFileName;
    private List<string> lines;
    private string originalFileText;
    //private List<string> formattedLines;

    public PCCBill(string displayFileName)
    {
        this.ImportFileName = displayFileName;
    }

    public string ImportFileName
    {
        get { return importFileName; }
        set
        {
            this.importFileName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ImportFileName));
        }
    }

    public List<string> Lines
    {
        get { return lines; }
        set
        {
            this.lines = value;
            string txt = "";
            foreach (string line in this.lines)
            {
                txt += line + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            this.OriginalFileText = txt;
        }
    }

    public string OriginalFileText
    {
        get { return originalFileText;  }
        set
        {
            this.originalFileText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(OriginalFileText));
        }
    }
    /*public string FormattedFileText
    {
        get
        {
            string txt = "";
            foreach(string line in this.formattedLines)
            {
                txt += line + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            return txt;
        }
    }*/


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
    }
```

I have the x:Bind set in the View with OneWay Mode:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="FileNameTxtBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="15,0" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Bill.ImportFileName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="OrgPreviewTxtBlock" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Bill.OriginalFileText, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: I tested your code in a sample app and works. Are you sure your ``this.OriginalFileText = txt;`` line is called?

Comment: It's called, I also tried updating the view to bind to a property of the viewModel, and set the model's event property to the viewModel to update the binded property in the viewModel.  The event is raised and assigns the value, but the UI is still not updating.

Comment: Something is off here. Like I said, I tested your code and works for me. Could be a typo. For example, the UI won't update with ``RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(originalFileText));`` (lower case **o**).

Comment: Can you show us the code that connects the view model to the UI? Is this code executed exactly once? In the past I ran into errors when the instance of the my view model was not longer attached to the UI, because I accicently overwrote it with another instance of the view model class.